# cannot invoke initializer for type 'int' with an argument list of type 'NSString?'

Tags: swift

I am developing an app, where I have to read from web page. Or that is my solution for my app. It is reading from database, but I have errors when using JSON, so i tried this, because i have to read only one number. But when I download the webpage code, which is only "3" for example, just the number. In my program it is like (NSString?), is there any possibilities to convert it in INT?

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://servis.dronysitmp.cz/cteni.php")

    if url != nil {

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            //print(data)                
            if error == nil {

                let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) as NSString!

                let urlContent2: Int = Int(urlContent)
                print(urlContent!)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: Yes. look for "String to Int in Swift" in SO or Google ?

Comment: Use `Int("3")` for converting a String number representation to `Int`.

Comment: @Larme Yes, i tried this: let myInt: Int = Int(myString)....but i have error, that I can not from 'NSString?' to 'Int'

Comment: Why is is NSString? How did you serialized your JSON? I'm wondering if you are not mixing Swift 3 Types and old Objective-C Foundation (NSStuff).

Comment: @Larme i have edited my question

Comment: @Moritz the data is not JSON

Comment: Then please remove the part of your question where you're talking about JSON, because this is confusing.

Comment: `as NSString!` => `as String` instead (cf. my last comment). Also, I wouldn't do a "!", but check with a `if let` maybe instead.

Answer (score 1):

Josef, you’re not using common Swift patterns correctly. Instead of

```
let url = ...
if url != nil { ...
```

you would boost legibility by using this pattern:

```
if let url = ... {
```

In this case `url` is non-optional and cannot be `nil`. This construct is called “safe-unwrapping an optional” in Swift.

The next part of code that doesn’t look too nice is this:

```
let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) as NSString!
```

If you use a `NSString`constructor then there’s no need to cast it to NSString. What you’re probably trying to achieve is to get around the fact that `NSString(data:encoding:)` returns an optional—which it does for good reason as it cannot guarantee to always be successful. You should therefore rather do something like this:

```
if let urlContent = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) {
```

which makes sure that no crash will occur in such cases when `NSString` cannot convert the supplied `data` into an integer.

Finally, please consider these two general advices:

1. Never use force-unwrapping of an optional without prior testing for `nil`. I. e. never do this: `variable!` if you cannot be 100% sure that `variable` is non-nil. So `NSString(data: data!,...` in your example is not good.
2. Try to avoid Foundation classes (NS stuff like NSString, etc.) if pure Swift substitutes exist. In your example: `if let urlContent = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii.rawValue) {`. This makes your code “swifter” which is what Swift coders prefer…

Comment: Why do you force unwrap `data` in bullet point 2 when bullet point 1 properly states that you should avoid force unwrapping optionals?

Comment: You’re right. I simply copied this part of the code from the original question and left it unchanged. I’ll add a comment to my answer.